# Finding the Radius of Convergence of Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of the series:
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 5^{(-1)^n}z^n$$

This was an old homework question.  I tried finding the radius of convergence by using the ratio test, but the professor wrote on my homework that the ratio test does not work.  I, therefore, am not sure how to or what method to use to find the radius of convergence.  The answer should be $1$ according to the back of the book.  Any help, suggestions, and pointers are welcomed.  I have attached the question as a picture.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the summation in

$$5(1+z^2+z^4+z^6+\cdots)+\frac15(z+z^3+z^5+z^7+\cdots).$$ This is allowed as all terms are positive.

The radius of convergence of the sum will be the smallest of the two radii.

---

When it converges, the value of the sum is

$$\frac5{1-z^2}+\frac z{5(1-z^2)}.$$

Comment: What are the two radii specifically?

Comment: @bob: your job to find that.

Comment: Isn't one of the radii 5 and the other 1/5?

Comment: @BOB: no, use the theory. (And if that helps, consider $t=z^2$.)

Comment: I'm confused, could you please explain, what theory?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand this stuff.  Thanks.

Comment: @bob: convergence criteria.

Comment: The first one is a geometric series, so it converges for |z|<1, is that correct?

Comment: @bob: actually for $z^2<1$, but this is equivalent. For the other, just factor out $z$.

Comment: But doesn't the 5 change things?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|=1$, the sequence $(5^{(-1)^n}z^n)$ is neither convergent to $0$ nor unbounded, so radius of convergence is $1$.

Another way to look at it : if $|z|<1$, $\left|5^{(-1)^n}z^n\right|\le 5|z|^n$ which is the term of a convergent geometric series, so radius is greater than $1$, but if $|z|>1$, $\left|5^{(-1)^n}z^n\right|\le \frac15|z|^n$ which is the term of a divergent geometric series.